# GAS : How to format all empty cells in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to format all empty/blank cells in a whole sheet with a white background but I don't find the best method to retrieve a range that can handle all those empty/blank cells.
I don't want to create a conditional rule, I'd like to handle it within a script.

What kind of method should I use ?
Thanks a lot !

P.S : I'm a newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) there's two functions that pertain to rows and columns that can give you the exact number of cells in the sheet with one mathematical operation.

Comment: Thanks Cooper for your answer. What kind of mathematical operation should I use to get the range of all the empty cells ?